# PushViewController after presentModalViewController like in Apples Alarm Clock app

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, model-view-controller, tableview, pushviewcontroller

my Question is quite simple. 
I have an add-button. When I tap on it --> presentmodelviewController presents a UIViewController, which contains a simple Table with cells.

When I tap on a Cell, i want to display a new View using pushViewController, which automatically creates a "back Button".

At the top of it in this new View i have a Textfield, where I can enter some Text. 
When I tap the back-button, the view slides back to the add-View (which was presented using modalView...). 
Now i want the text edited in the view before to be placed in the Label of the first row (cell) on which I tapped.

So I want to do this for 5 cells. Each of them presenting another xib.

Please, can anyone help?
Thanks for your helpful replies.

Answer (score 4):

You should first present a modalviewcontroller that has a navigationcontroller within. Within this view, you can now push other view controllers.

Comment: An example: UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController]; [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController]; [navController release];